# REST api, GET and timezone as param or header?

Tags: rest, http-headers, timezone

What would be correct/preferred REST api design to fetch data that depends on timezone?

I was thinking about simply adding timezone as an URL param, so:

```
$ curl www.api.example.com/data?timezone="Europe/Amsterdam"
```

But someone suggested to use custom header for that in similar manner like github does:

```
$ curl -H "X-Time-Zone: Europe/Amsterdam" www.api.example.com/data
```

https://developer.github.com/v3/#using-the-time-zone-header

I wonder what are benefits of using header here instead of param? Is there any design pattern behind such decision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's entirely up to you, whether you wish to accept an input parameter in the path, querystring, header, or content body.

However, one could argue that a header makes sense when it is not the primary concern of the api you're calling.  For example, if your api was specifically to retrieve the properties of a time zone, then I would recommend passing it on the url, either on the querystring as you suggested in your question, or on the path (www.api.example.com/timezone/europe/amsterdam).

Also note that the example you gave that uses the parameter in a header is a POST call.  Though it's not prohibited, it usually doesn't make a lot of sense to pass querystring parameters in a POST.  By passing the time zone as a header, the body of the message can focus on what is being posted.

Comment: Also, to avoid all ambiguity *always* add timezone information to your serialized responses, e.g. the `+00:00` in `2019-01-22T14:10:35+00:00`.

Comment: @PieterEnnes - that's unrelated to what was asked here, and that's a time zone offset, not a time zone identifier. Also sometimes yes, but no - not always. There are plenty of reasons not to include the offset.

Comment: @PieterEnnes just to word this even strong. It's a good idea to add a `Z` to the end, but almost never a good idea to include a UTC offset. You want olson timezone identifiers.

Comment: @MattJohnson Well, I would call it "related" at least. In what situation would you not add time zone info in your responses?

Comment: Sure, it's related.  So are the thousands of other questions and answers with the [tag:timezone] tag.  This particular question is about passing time zone identifiers.  Nothing more, nothing less.   As far as when you wouldn't attach a time zone offset to an output value, consider whole dates (birthdays, business days, etc.) and recurring schedules (future events, alarm clocks, business hours, etc.).   But again, there are already long questions and answers on that elsewhere in the [tag:timezone] tag.